# How to deploy ASP.NET MVC 4 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

This is my first experience developing the MVC app and I started with MVC 4, I have used my own template and maintained different directory structure as :

[image]

And referenced resources like :

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/regionBase.gif")" style="width:80%;" onclick="" usemap="#regionMap" id="regionBase">

       bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/jquery.bonsai.css",
                "~/Content/tooltipster.css"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.tooltipster.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.bonsai.js",
                        "~/Scripts/imageMapResizer.js"
                        ));
```

Everything works well till its runs in visual studio, the moment I Publish(using Publish Method: File System) to the localhost build doesn't includes: images from Content folder, JS from the "Scripts" folder.

Not able to figure If I am missing any step, there is any other way to Deploy the MVC 4 project, beside the options mentioned under the Publish Tools.

Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on each file that you want to deploy in solution explorer, then choose 'Include In Project'. then if you publish the project, the included file comes to publish folder.
You can prevent files to publish with same method and choose 'Exclude From Project'.

Comment: Ahh silly mistake, took my half a day, Thanks a ton Saman, by default when you add a resource are they excluded from solution ?

Comment: My Pleasure. If you copy your files, then paste into solution explorer, automatically files are being included.